# unhandled error event in node js Error: spawn ENOENT at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11)

Tags: node.js

----This is my code, FILE NAME is **test.js** -----

```
var curl = require('curlrequest');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var options = {
    url: "https://api.github.com/repos/jiangmiao/node-curl",
    encoding: null,
  //, headers: { 'foo bar': 'wha' }
};


curl.request(options, function (err, data, meta) {

    data = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    console.log(data);

});
```

---- getting error ---

```
Z:\arun\NODE>node test.js

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:975:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:766:34)
```

--------------------- my node details is------------ 
{ http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.5',
  v8: '3.14.5.8',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.5',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1e',
  npm: '1.2.18',
  'email-node': '1.0.0' }

---------------my system config---
 64-bit operating system WINDOWS 8, x64-based processor

i am doing for curl operation

Comment: You can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-to-debug-any-node-js-child-process-error-spawn-enoent for details on how to solving this yourself